# Delegate.BeginInvoke doesn't appear to do anything on a different PC

Tags: c#, winforms, delegates

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.icon_testLOAD.Visible = true;
    this.icon_testOK.Visible = false;
    this.icon_testBAD.Visible = false;

    this.debug("Test Service Button Clicked");

    rabbitmq_test t = new rabbitmq_test(button_rabbitmq_test);

    this.debug("Calling BeginInvoke on button_rabbitmq_test delegate");
    t.BeginInvoke(null, null);
}
```

So I have this button click event. The first three lines are turning on and off PictureBoxes that contain icons.

this.debug() merely calls EventLog.WriteEntry()

The button_rabbitmq_test method looks like:

```
protected void button_rabbitmq_test()
{
    this.debug("Creating new rabbitmq connection factory");
    IConnection connection;
    try
    {
        ConnectionFactory rq_factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        rq_factory.Port = Convert.ToInt16(this.psistats_config.rabbitmq_port);
        rq_factory.HostName = this.psistats_config.rabbitmq_server;
        rq_factory.UserName = this.psistats_config.rabbitmq_username;
        rq_factory.Password = this.psistats_config.rabbitmq_password;
        rq_factory.RequestedConnectionTimeout = 15000;

        this.debug("Creating new rabbitmq connection");
        connection = rq_factory.CreateConnection();

        this.debug("Changing icon to successful");
        rabbitmq_icon_delegate d = new rabbitmq_icon_delegate(this.testOK);
        connection.Close();
        this.test_button.Invoke(d);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.Close();
        }

        this.debug("Failed testing the rabbit server");
        this.debug(exc.Message);
        this.debug(exc.StackTrace);

        rabbitmq_icon_delegate d = new rabbitmq_icon_delegate(this.testFailed);
        this.test_button.Invoke(d);
    }
}
```

This code works fine on the computer I'm doing the development on. The method executes, the event log is populated as expected. However, when I run this application on a second machine, the BeginInvoke method doesn't seem to do anything at all and I have absolutely no idea why.

The last message I see in the event log is "Calling BeginInvoke..." but the event logs from the method that performs the actual test are not seen anywhere.

The application is also not frozen. I can still use it.

I am at a loss as to what I am doing wrong and any advice would be welcome.

Comment: Are you using the static WriteEntry method of the EventLog or the instanced one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is fundamentally flawed, you **must** call the delegate's EndInvoke() method.  Best done by *not* passing null as the first argument, use a [callback method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2288159/17034) that then calls EndInvoke().

If you don't call EndInvoke() then you'll leak resources, lasts for 10 minutes.  And the ultimate problem you are asking about, you can't see an exception that was raised by the method.  So you cannot find out why it didn't work. Calling EndInvoke() rethrows that exception.

Using a delegate's BeginInvoke() method is a low-level programming technique that's best avoided, too easy to make mistakes like this and too difficult to deal with exceptions.  Use a BackgroundWorker or a Task instead.

Comment: Agreed.  Microsoft is partly at fault here, for giving the same name to two methods which are used for similar things (triggering execution on another thread) but have very different semantics.  `Control.BeginInvoke` which takes a delegate as a parameter and does not require `EndInvoke`, and the delegate's own `BeginInvoke` method, which does require `EndInvoke` as you pointed out.